# Which Linux syscall is used to get a thread's ID?

Tags: multithreading, unix, operating-system, pthreads

I have to implement a wrapper function that serves as `pthread_self()` to get a pthread ID but I've been searching and haven´t found which syscall does this. Reading another post from Stack O. I know `clone()` is used to create threads, also that I can trace the syscalls with `ptrace()` but before tracing it by hand...could someone knows which syscall is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about syscall 0xe0, [gettid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid)?

> gettid() returns the caller's thread ID (TID). In a single-threaded process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned by getpid(2)). In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one has a unique TID. For further details, see the discussion of CLONE_THREAD in clone(2).

Comment: but I found gettid returns the OS specific thread ID, not the ID relative for the process...or maybe I got confused. Evenmore, will it return the TID within the process?

Comment: quoting: "The thread ID returned by this call is not the same thing as a POSIX thread ID" so?

Comment: Hm, seems like you are right. These two are not the same. The man page for pthreads_self even says so: "Thread identifiers should be considered opaque: any attempt to use a thread ID other than in pthreads calls is nonportable and can lead to unspecified results. The thread ID returned by pthread_self() is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2)."

Comment: However, if you use the libc clone, you should get the TID as a return value. From the clone(2) man page: "A new thread's TID is available as the function result returned to the caller of clone(), and a thread can obtain its own TID using gettid(2)."

Comment: So in conclusion, if you use clone(), you should get the TID as a return value and be able to use gettid() to get that same TID again. There is no point in wanting to get the number pthread_self() would return if you are not creating the threads using pthread_create(), or is there?

Comment: yep, but still not knowing which system call it uses, gotta do more research

Comment: sorry about last comment, actually with clone is the real answer because clone has underlying the syscall sys_clone

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 different IDs for a linux process thread:  pid, pthread id, and tid.

The 'pid' is global and equivalent to the parent process id, and is easily obtained by 'getpid()'.  This value is unique, but only for the duration of an the active process assigned the given id.  This value may be 'recycled' for a new process after a process is terminated and new ones are spawned.  This value is the same across all threads, within a process. This value is what you'll see in top, and htop, 'ps -ef', and pidstat.

The 'pthread id' is reported by pthread_create() and phtread_self().  This is value is unique only within the process, and only for the duration of the assign thread.  This value may be 'recycled' as threads are terminated and spawned. This value is not unique across the system, nor across threads that have been terminated and started.  This value is NOT visible outside of a program.  This value is opaque and may be a pointer or structure depending on the platform.

The 'tid' Thread id is reported by gettid(). This was introduced to Linux 2.4, and does not appear to be available on other platforms. This value is unique within the process and across the system.  This value is reported by top and htop, and 'pidstat -t'.  I'm not 100% certain, but suspect this value can be 'recycled' as processes are terminated and spawned.   This is the value that appears in the Linux tools 'top','htop', 'pidstat -t', and 'ps -efL', when shown threads.

Documentation for gettid: [linux.die.net/gettid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid)

You can obtain 'gettid()' through:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pthread.h>
```

My CentOS 6.5 is not properly setup and missing the gettid prototype, though the documentation says it should be present through the above #includes.  Here is a macro that mimics 'gettid':

```
#ifndef gettid
// equivalent to:  pid_t  gettid(void)
#define gettid() syscall(SYS_gettid)
#endif
```

Be aware that since this is a syscall(), you'll gain efficiency by caching the result and avoiding repeatedly using the syscall().

Answer (score 1):

In glibc, `pthread_self()` does not do system calls, but returns a pointer to a `struct pthread`, located in the TSD segment.

Comment: yeah, but I need to implement the system call whose capable of getting a thread ID

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpfull.

UINT32 tid= syscall(SYS_gettid);